# Fast implementation of N-Grams in Python

Tags: python, n-gram

I have this function that I would like to optimize. 
It would pass over thousands of rows.

It currently works but it is very slow to apply it to a column with so many records.
Can anyone think of a much faster way to run this script?
About the total number of records, it's taking me about 45 seconds approx.

```
from ngram import NGram
import time 

d = {'col1': ["instruments",'instruments music','instrum 2']}
d = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

start = time.time()
d['ratio'] = d['col1'].apply(lambda x: ngram.NGram.compare(x,'instrum'))
print time.time() - start
```